# Assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found while running docker with dotnet-core project

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I have message error like this:

```
Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery', version: '1.1.1', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'
```

And its happening when I run this commands:

```
dotnet build -o obj/Docker/publish -c Release
dotnet publish -o obj/Docker/publish -c Release
docker build -t webapi .
docker run -p 80:80 --name api webapi
```

But in project, I can see reference

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery" Version="1.1.1" />
```

And in my Dockerfile I think I put all necessary information:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

Have you any idea what can be a problem for this situation?

UPDATE:
After `dotnet restore` communicate change into:

```
Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions', version: '1.1.0', path: 'lib/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'
```

And its still this same situation. But now after restore its don't change anymore.

Comment: Is that the only package reference that is not found?

Comment: It is problem because was one moment after `dotnet restore` I've got a problem with `microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions` with this same communicate and this same situation with reference.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this error I have to changed my WORKDIR. It was reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/issues/213#issuecomment-288520623)

```
WORKDIR /app
```